# SQL Error Logs not viewable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-agent

I am having an issue on viewing the SQL Error logs on SSMS. I'm aware that I'm also able to view the error logs by going to the folder where the error logs are stored. I have tried verifying if my service account has permission to access the error log location (read/write). Also my service account is granted sysadmin in SSMS. Still I'm unable to view the SQL Error Logs in SSMS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. In SQL Server Management Studio, select Object Explorer. ...
2. In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of SQL Server, and then expand that instance.
3. Find and expand the Management section (assuming you have permissions to see it).
4. Right-click SQL Server Logs, select View, and then choose SQL Server Log

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15